# Convert Delim File to list Objects using Python

Tags: python

I have a delim data file as given below

```
DAYPART_ID|NAME|LABEL|START_TIME|END_TIME|WEEKEDAYS|STYLE|DAYPART_SET_ID|ORDER
1|Early AM|6:00 am - 9:00 am|6|9|12345|gold|1|01
2|Daytime|9:00 am - 4:00 pm|9|16|12345|red|1|02
```

I need to conver it to the following type of Json list file

```
[
{
"STYLE": "gold", 
"NAME": "Early AM", 
"START_TIME": 6, 
"DAYPART_SET_ID": 1, 
"LABEL": "6:00 am - 9:00 am", 
"DAYPART_ID": 1, 
"END_TIME": 9, 
"ORDER": 01, 
"WEEKEDAYS": 12345
},
{
"STYLE": "red", 
"NAME": "Daytime", 
"START_TIME": 9, 
"DAYPART_SET_ID": 1, 
"LABEL": "9:00 am - 4:00 pm", 
"DAYPART_ID": 2, 
"END_TIME": 16, 
"ORDER": 02, 
"WEEKEDAYS": 12345
}
]
```

So although it a JSON file but it is a little modified like the numeric fields wont have quotes and we have extra third brackets in the file and there is a comma between each record apart from having a end curly braces.

I wrote a coded like below

```
import csv
import json

csv.register_dialect('pipe', delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

with open('Infile', "r") as csvfile:
    with open(outtfile, 'w') as outfile:
           for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='pipe'):
            data= row
            json.dump(data, outfile, sort_keys = False, indent = 0,ensure_ascii=True)
```

But it did not give me the exact result. I intended. Can Anyone help here?

Comment: Could you attach expected output AND your output? As it is written now, it's fairly ambiguous.

Comment: Added expected output and current output

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is actually dumping each row to destination file. These objects has no knowledge of being in list therefore list syntax of json file is missing from your output file. A solution to your problem would be to read all objects to list, and dump the **list itself** afterwards.

For numbers - simply list all columns with expected type of int and convert them before adding to `objects` list.

```
import csv
import json

csv.register_dialect('pipe', delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
numeric_columns = ['START_TIME', 'END_TIME', 'WEEKEDAYS', 'DAYPART_SET_ID', 'DAYPART_ID']
objects = []
with open('infile', "r") as csvfile:
    for o in csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='pipe'):
        for k in numeric_columns:
            o[k] = int(o[k])
        objects.append(o)

with open('outfile', 'w') as dst:
    json.dump(objects, dst, indent=2)
```

Comment: Thanks! But The problem with this solution is that the numeric values are still coming in Quotes. But I want only text values in Quotes and the numeric fields in without Quotes. Check my needed ouput.

Comment: @PritamRoy: 0x where x is a digit is not a valid json number literal.

Comment: 0x will remain as 0x only but 1 or 12345 should be comming as 1 and not "1"  or "12345" should come as 12345. Any way to get this?